# How to show number of field added using jQuery add/remove field?

Tags: jquery, html

I am using jQuery to add/remove more `div`. Here is my code:

**jQuer Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('#oneway').click(function() {
      $('.oneway_wrap').show();
      $('.return_wrap').hide();      
   });
});

// Add/remove code
var counting = 0;
$("body").on("click",".add_button",function(){

   // this is not the correct way to increment...  :(
   $('.counting').html(counting);

   var html = $(".oneway_wrap").first().clone();
   $(html).find(".change").html("<a class='btn btn-danger remove remove_more'>- Remove</a>&nbsp;<button class='btn add_button add_more'><strong>Add More (+)</strong></button>");
   $(".oneway_wrap").last().after(html);
   counting++;
});
```

**HTML Code:**

```
<!-- oneway wrap -->
<div class="oneway_wrap">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group">
         <div class="col-md-12">
            <h5 class="badge badge-success counting">Details 1</h5><hr><br/>
         </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6">
         <div class="form-group">
            <label>Guest Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="ow_gname[]" class="form-control" placeholder="Guest name">
         </div>
      </div>                                 
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <div class="form-group change">
            <a class="btn add_button add_more"><strong>Add More (+)</strong></a>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div><!-- oneway wrap end -->

<!-- return wrap -->
<div class="return_wrap">
   <!-- same html code here... for retrun way with return classes -->
</div><!-- return wrap end -->
```

This add/remove is working fine. **Now I want to show the number of rows added or removed in this class(counting)**

```
<h5 class="badge badge-success counting">Details 1</h5><hr><br/>
```

**So, If 2 extra row added then it will be `Details 2, Details 3...`**

In jQuery I am using this: `$('.counting').html(counting);` But I don't think it's a correct way and the result is always the same.

I mean, If 2 extra row added then the counting is showing Details 2, Details 2 but should be Details 2, Details 3, Details 4...

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can generate the innerHTML like this

```
$("body").on("click",".add_button",function(){
   var html = $(".oneway_wrap").first().clone();
   $(html).find(".change").html("<a class='btn btn-danger remove remove_more'>- Remove</a>&nbsp;<button class='btn add_button add_more'><strong>Add More (+)</strong></button>");
   $(".oneway_wrap").last().after(html);

   $('.counting').each(function(i, elm) {
      $(elm).text('Detail ' + (i + 1));
   });
});
```

Comment: I am checking it now.

Comment: It's somehow working / not working. I mean now it's show me Details 1, Details 2 Details 3 in every div `(.oneway_wrap)`. Its should be show Deails 1 in first div, Details 2 in second div, Details 3 in third div and so on....

Comment: sorry I got your requirement wrong. I have update my answer. and here is an example https://jsfiddle.net/5x1adg7r/3/

Comment: Wow, Great, It's working fine. but can you tell me why you use `(i, elm)`?

Comment: (i, elm) is the parameter for the callback for jquery each function. you can google for jquery .each function to get more information. Hope that this is ok. thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can use .length to count rows. please see following code snippet.

```
 var counting = 0;
 $("body").on("click",".add_button",function(){

   // Now i think this is proper way to count rows  :(
   $('.counting').html("Details "+$(document).find(".row").length);

   var html = $(".oneway_wrap").first().clone();
   $(html).find(".change").html("<a class='btn btn-danger remove remove_more'>- Remove</a>&nbsp;<button class='btn add_button add_more'><strong>Add More (+)</strong></button>");
   $(".oneway_wrap").last().after(html);
   counting++;
});
```

Comment: let me check this.

Comment: you can try this $(document).find(".row").length